# ajax doesn't work for default domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dns

I have an ajax script, in the main index.php page, that fetches data from an absolute URL: 'http://www.example.com/ajax'

The problem is that the fetch works when I run it from http://www.example.com, but I just go to http://example.com, though the rest of the page loads just fine, the ajax script won't load.

Does anyone know of any possible reason why this may be the case?

Comment: foo.com belongs to Digimedia. Please use example.com/net/org for examples, that is what they are there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) operates on a hostname basis, not a domain basis.

Use relative URIs, or pick one hostname as canonical and redirect all traffic from one to the other.

Comment: Wouldn't setting document.domain to 'example.com' help in his case?

Comment: It says it would at the page I linked to. Redirecting to a canonical URL is cleaner and more certain to work cross-browser though — the ability to set `document.domain` is non-standard (and contradicts the DOM specification).

Comment: my questions is...how would you redirect from www.example.com to example.com.....it appears that www is treated as a special subdomain and I can't seem to add it to the redirection menu in cpanel

Comment: I've never used cpanel and probably never will, so I haven't a clue. That really deserves another question.

Comment: I'd try serverfault for a cpanel related question, tho.